# Lightning Scheduler Flow Variable {!ServiceAppointment.IsAnonymousBooking}

Tags: lightning, lightning-scheduler

The OOTB Salesforce LightningScheduler flows specify a variable reference to an objects field that does not exist. {!ServiceAppointment.IsAnonymousBooking}
Getting this error on Intitial Assignment in the the flow when saving it. Using flow 'Inbuond New Guest Appointment.'
[image]

Looked at other sandboxes and see the same issue. Has anyone else experienced this and/or did you simply deleted the flow variable reference or add a field to the object ?

Answer (score 0):

The field does exist, it's in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_serviceappointment.htm). Make sure you have at least Read Field Level Security to the field on your profile or granted by a permission set. Flows honor field level security, and will display errors if you don't have the correct permissions, even if you're a System Administrator.

Comment: thanks. I reviewed the SOAP doco but the (ServiceAppointment) object itself does not contain the field. So I added this field as a checkbox and was able to add it to the flow and delete the OOTB flow variable. Let me know if I am missing what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

That field does exist: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_serviceappointment.htm

If you add a custom field, it will get ignored and will not add any value in the final saved appointment. However, if you set value in the assignment stage for this standard field, it will get saved to the appointment record, which flow will create.

[UPDATE]: If you do not care about anonymous booking, you can simply delete this assignment. No need to create a new field!

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot delete this fields from the assignment step in flow. Nor can you add any values to existing fields in the assignment as Salesforce will throw an error on the save due to this field. So just created a new assignment in-line and set the fields I needed ignoring the OOTB assignment.